# Optimizing Google Earth Engine cloud cover for Sentinel 5p

Tags: google-earth-engine, optimization, code-review

I am trying to generate cloud free Sentinel 5p images, I have a basic cloud detection code working but it runs very slowly (most likely due to nested map and reduce features).

Is there a way to do this better?

```
var coll,coll1,median,median1;
button.onClick(function(){
  chart_panel.clear();
  Map.clear();
  first();
  second();
});

var first=function(){
  coll=p_var3.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(start_month_var,start_month_var,'month') ).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(start_year_var,start_year_var,'year'))
  .filterBounds(city_var1).select(p_var2);
  chartfunction1();
  median = coll.median().clip(city_var1);
  var Extrema=median.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.minMax(),city_var1,250);
  var vis_params=ee.Dictionary({
    min: Extrema.getNumber(p_var4),
    max: Extrema.getNumber(p_var5),
    opacity: 1.0,
    palette: ["blue","red","yellow","green","cyan","black","purple"],
    bands:[p_var2]
  });  
  Map.addLayer(median,vis_params.getInfo(), 'true-color composite');
};

var second=function(){
  coll1=p_var3.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(end_month_var,end_month_var,'month') ).filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(end_year_var,end_year_var,'year'))
  .filterBounds(city_var1).select(p_var2);
  chartfunction2();
   median1 = coll1.median().clip(city_var1);
  var Extrema1=median1.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.minMax(),city_var1,250);

  var vis_params1=ee.Dictionary({
    min:Extrema1.getNumber(p_var4),
    max:Extrema1.getNumber(p_var5),
    opacity: 1.0,
    palette:["blue","red","yellow","green","cyan","black","purple"],
    bands:[p_var2]
   }); 
   Map.addLayer(median1,vis_params1.getInfo(), 'true-color composite2');
};

var chartfunction1=function(){
  var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: coll.select(p_var2),
    regions: city_var1,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
    band:[p_var2],
    scale: 30,
    xProperty:'system:time_start', 
    seriesProperty: 'label'
  }).setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Pollution',
    vAxis: {title: p_var1},
    hAxis: {title: 'Month'},
    pointSize:3,
    series: {
              0: {color: 'green'} 
            }
  });
  chart_panel.add(chart);
};
var chartfunction2=function(){
  var chart1 = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: coll1.select(p_var2),
    regions: city_var1,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
    band:[p_var2],
    scale: 30,
    xProperty:'system:time_start', 
    seriesProperty: 'label'
  }).setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Pollution',
    vAxis: {title: p_var1},
    hAxis: {title: 'Month'},
    pointSize:3,
    series: {
              0: {color: 'blue'} 
            }
  });
  chart_panel.add(chart1);
};
```

Comment: For code review there is the [codereview.se] Stack Exchange.